# Grep: Use colour for one of multiple expressions

Tags: command-line, grep

Is it possible to have grep search for multiple expressions, but only colour a specific one of them?

Example of what I'm after:

```
cat file | grep -e foo --colour -e bar
```

Output (where bold represents coloured):

foo baz

**bar** baz

qux foo

foo **bar**

Answer (score 1):

PCRE can be abused so that there is a match but nothing matched that would be highlighted:

```
grep -P 'foo.*\K$|bar' input
```

Comment: Or `grep -P '(?=foo)|bar'` (which would also work with older versions of PCRE).

Answer (score 0):

A solution (though not particularly elegant) is to use multiple grep queries.

```
cat file | grep -e foo -e bar | grep -9999 --colour -e bar
```

Note: The `-9999` flag is a hack to get grep to output a lot of lines from stdin. It is possible to increase the value if it is required.

Comment: Or `<file grep -e foo -e bar | grep --colour -e '^' -e bar`